# something wrong with randomizer method

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using UIKit;

namespace iOSMemoryGame
{
    public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
    {
        #region vars

    List<String> imgArr = new List<String>();

    float gameViewWidth;
    int gridSize = 6;

    ArrayList tilesArr = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList coordsArr = new ArrayList();

    #endregion

    public ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {

    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidAppear(animated);

        // make sure Game View is Laid Out
        gameView.LayoutIfNeeded();
        gameViewWidth = (float)gameView.Frame.Size.Width;

        // let's load all of our images into an array
        for (int i = 1; i <= 18; i++)
        {
            imgArr.Add("img_" + i.ToString() + ".png");
        }

        // let's make a call to tileMaker
        tileMaker();

        // let's call the randomizer
        randomizer();
    }

    private void randomizer()
    {
        // we are gonna go through our tiles in ORDER
        // and we are gonna assign a new center to them RANDOMLY

        foreach (UIView any in tilesArr)
        {
            // UIImageView thisTile = (UIImageView)tilesArr[i];

            Random myRand = new Random();
            int randomIndex = myRand.Next(0, coordsArr.Count);

            CoreGraphics.CGPoint newRandCenter = (CoreGraphics.CGPoint)coordsArr[randomIndex];
            any.Center = newRandCenter;

            coordsArr.RemoveAt(randomIndex);
        }
    }

    private void tileMaker()
    {
        float tileWidth = gameViewWidth / gridSize;

        float xCenter = tileWidth / 2;
        float yCenter = tileWidth / 2;

        int imgCounter = 0;

        for (int h = 0; h < gridSize; h++)
        {
            for (int v = 0; v < gridSize; v++)
            {
                UIImageView tileImgView = new UIImageView();

                CoreGraphics.CGPoint newCenter = new CoreGraphics.CGPoint(xCenter, yCenter);

                tileImgView.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, tileWidth - 5, tileWidth - 5);

                String imgName = imgArr[imgCounter];
                tileImgView.Image = new UIImage(imgName);
                tileImgView.Center = newCenter;

                // user CAN interact with this image view
                tileImgView.UserInteractionEnabled = true;

                // adding the new image view to the array
                tilesArr.Add(tileImgView);

                gameView.AddSubview(tileImgView);

                xCenter = xCenter + tileWidth;
                imgCounter++;

                if (imgCounter == gridSize * gridSize / 2)
                {
                    imgCounter = 0;
                }
            }

            xCenter = tileWidth / 2;
            yCenter = yCenter + tileWidth;
        }
    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    partial void Rst4Button_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    partial void Rst6Button_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

}

Something is wrong with the randomizer method (with it being commented out it runs fine) but i dont know what (im just a beginner following this here (https://www.udemy.com/xamarin-native-ios-memory-game-csharp/learn/v4/content).

it gives me again a out of range error.

[image: Error]

Comment: One general comment - you don't need to create a new `Random` object in every iteration of your loop. This line: `Random myRand = new Random();` should be outside (and before) the `foreach` loop.

Comment: Any chance the coordsArr could be empty? That'd cause the exception you are seeing

Comment: please do NOT post code and errors as images.  Take the time to paste the text of the message and format it correctly.

Comment: where you fill coordsArr? It seems like coordsArr has no elements

Comment: try this: int randomIndex = myRand.Next(0, coordsArr.Count - 1);

Comment: Exactly. If `coordsArray` is empty, Random.Next(0, 0) will return `0`, and your code will try to access element `0`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: @Jason Ok, i will remember next time

Comment: @Jason I think his code is correct - the `max` value (in `rnd.Next`) is an **exclusive** upper bound. You need to pass the `.Count` to include the last index.

Comment: you're right, it is exclusive.

Comment: @Jason when i set it minus 1 i get this error: Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException. 'minValue' cannot be greater than maxValue. Parameter name: minValue

Comment: @Paludis - this would be a great time for you to use to learn the debugger.  When the code breaks you need to examine the values of the variables and objects and figure out why you're getting an invalid index

Comment: @Jason I do that by setting breakpoints and then stepping through right?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your array has not been populated yet, so the `Count` is `0`. But even though the `max` value of the `myRand.Next(min, max)` is an **exclusive** upper bound, if you call `myRand.Next(0, 0)`, you will get back `0`. Then you get an exception when the code tries to access `coordsArr[0]` and there are no items to access.

One way to avoid the exception is to check for the array to contain any items first. Also notice I moved the `new Random()` code line outside of the `foreach` loop:

```
if (coordsArr.Count > 0)
{
    Random myRand = new Random();

    foreach (UIView any in tilesArr)
    {
        // UIImageView thisTile = (UIImageView)tilesArr[i];

        int randomIndex = myRand.Next(0, coordsArr.Count);

        CoreGraphics.CGPoint newRandCenter = (CoreGraphics.CGPoint)coordsArr[randomIndex];
        any.Center = newRandCenter;

        coordsArr.RemoveAt(randomIndex);
    }
}
else
{
    // Take some action if the array is empty?
}
```

Looking more closely at your code, however, it appears that you are looping over one array and doing something with another array. The reason for this is usually one of two things:

1. There is a typo, where the user typed the wrong array name inside the body of the loop, or inside the condition. To fix this, just change `coordsArr` to `tilesArr` (or vice versa) in the `foreach` loop code.
2. The person is populating two separate arrays with related items (so they both have the same number of items, and for any index i, `firstArray[i]` will be related to `secondArray[i]` in some way. If this is the case, then you are probably missing some code in your `tileMaker` loop that is supposed to add something to the `coordsArr` array.

Comment: What i just don't understand though is why the tutors code which is exactly the same works and mine doesn't?

Comment: Because somewhere in his code he puts items into his array.

Comment: Ok, it works now but the images of the puzzle games aren't randomized as they should be

Comment: Did you take the new Random line out of the loop? BTW, I added some more possible solutions to the answer.

Comment: it seems like i just had to add this line to the tilemaker():

Comment: coordsArr.Add(newCenter);